# An isomorphism between product of number fields, contains the same number of factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that we have an isomorphism of rings

$$f:K_1\oplus\cdots\oplus K_r\to K'_1\oplus\cdots\oplus K'_s,$$

with $K_i$'s and $K_j'$'s are a number fields, the sum and the product are componentwise.

$\textbf{My question:}$  $r=s$ and without loss of generality $K_j\approx K_j'$?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a product of $n$ fields there are exactly $2^n$ idempotent elements. That tells you that the number of factors is the same.

To get that the factors are the same up to order, you can use the fact that in a product of fields the factors are precisely the minimal ideals.

Comment: If you wanted to do the case of infinitely many factors, this argument would run into problems, but then you can instead use the fact that in a product of $n$ fields, there are exactly $n$ primitive idempotent elements.

Comment: The minimal prime ideals are of the form $\{0\}\oplus K_2\oplus\cdots\oplus K_r$, of this, the claim follows, right?

Comment: Yes, but that only gives you that they are $r$ in number, not that they are isomorphic up to permutation (at least, without extra work)